# angularjs ng-repeat filter by multi fields

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 selects in my form :

```
Categories(ng-model = categoryFilter) 
Divisions (ng-model = divisionFilter)
Groups (ng-model = groupFilter)
```

and I have a table where's i m getting a list of data.

The user can choose a category OR a division OR  a group, I want to filter the details table by the chosen filter.

The details request is returning data containing GROUPID, CATEGORYID, DIVISIONID i tried

```
ng-repeat="row in details | filter : {GROUPID : groupFilter}
```

All working fine and the table is filtering. I want to modify this filter to accept : group or division or category, not filtering for GROUPID only. Any idea?

Comment: I believe filter accepts functions. Just write one as `$scope.foo = function(item){ if(...){return true;} else{ return false; } }` and use it as `"... | filter : foo"`

Comment: `| filter : {GROUPID: groupFilter,  CATEGORYID: categoryFilter,  DIVISIONID: divisionFilter}`?